# Modify a cloned entity in aframe

Tags: clone, aframe

I am coding my second aframe project in order to better understand how the framework works. For a forest, I defined a prototype tree

```
<a-entity id="tree">
  <a-cylinder id="cylinder" radius="0.3" height="5" color="#754" position="0 2.5 0"></a-cylinder>
  <a-cone radius="2" height="4" color="#6d4" position="0 7 0"></a-cone>
</a-entity>
```

Then I clone this tree with the help of [this script](https://samsunginter.net/a-frame-components/dist/clone.js):

```
<a-entity clone="#tree" position="2 0 0"></a-entity>
```

Cloning works fine. But how can I modify the radius of the cylinder? Or is there a better way to clone entities in aframe?

Answer (score 0):

In order to move forward, I defined a dedicated component for a tree:

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('tree', {
  schema: {
    height: {type: 'number', default: 9.0},
    crown: {type: 'number', default: 2.0},
    trunk: {type: 'number', default: 0.3}
  },

  init: function () {
    let trunk = document.createElement('a-cylinder');
    trunk.setAttribute('radius', this.data.trunk);
    trunk.setAttribute('height', this.data.height * 5.0/9.0);
    trunk.setAttribute('color', "#754");
    trunk.object3D.position.y += this.data.height * 5.0/18.0;
    this.el.appendChild(trunk);

    let crown = document.createElement('a-cone');
    crown.setAttribute('radius-bottom', this.data.crown);
    crown.setAttribute('height', this.data.height * 4.0/9.0);
    crown.setAttribute('color', "#6d4");
    crown.object3D.position.y += this.data.height * 14.0/18.0;
    this.el.appendChild(crown);        
  }
});
</script>
```

The component then can be instantiated and its parameters modified:

```
<a-entity tree></a-entity>
<a-entity tree="crown: 4; trunk: 0.7; height: 12" position="3 0 0"></a-entity>
```

However, this solution follows the Class/Instance paradigm and not the Prototype-Pattern. And in an educational context, a solution that hides the javascript from students would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that A-Frame follows an entity component paradigm: different than class/instance or prototype inheritance. Your tree component configures an entity as a tree and other additional components can modify or add that initial configuration. You can expose students to the pattern. [The A-Frame documentation is a good starting point](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html)